# Using the identifier of an object to change settings in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

well i want this actually

```
<s:Button x="240" id="anything"  y="80" label="User 4" click="click_Handler(event.currentTarget.id)" />


protected function click_Handler(s:String)
{
s.width ="xx" ;
}
```

Well in this code of course s.width cant be done. any ideas about how to do this.  i must change the width when i click on the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the `id` of the object, or pass the object reference instead of just its `id` to the event handler. In the example you have given the `id` is `anything`. Make sure this is unique for each object instance in the MXML.

One option is to directly refer to the stage instance. The code will be like this

```
protected function click_Handler(s:String){
    anything.width ="xx" ;
}
```

The other option is to pass either the event object (which is a good practice) or at least the target object to event handler, and use that. The code will be like this:

```
<s:Button x="240" id="anything"  y="80" label="User 4" click="click_Handler(event)" />

protected function click_Handler(e:Event){
    ((DisplayObject)(e.currentTarget)).width = "xx"
}
```

Comment: the point is i want to input the id to the function. what i want to do is their are lot of buttons when i click on any button its own characteristics changes. so the button will pass its id and then using its id i can do  id.width ="xx"

Comment: @umar see my edit. For this pass the `event` object and use its `currentTarget` property